# Why my SharedPreference object is not showing updated result in Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

I am writing a code in Android to save the selected dates from the date picker. I am saving the dates in Sharedpreference object but the latest result is showing after closing and opening the app.

I thought there must be a refresh Activity is need to display latest saved result from SharedPreference object , so i had used AsyncTask and tried to get latest result but the app is not showing the latest result , whenever i closing the app and re-opening the app again then i can see the latest saved result.

**My Code:**

```
package com.example.date_pick;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

DatePicker pickerDate;
TextView info;

Button btn;


Button btn12;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

     info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);

  final SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Demo", 0);


   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
   {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                            final Dialog dia = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

                            dia.requestWindowFeature(dia.getWindow().FEATURE_NO_TITLE);       

                            dia.setContentView(R.layout.mydate);


                            btn12 = (Button)dia.findViewById(R.id.btn1);

                            pickerDate = (DatePicker)dia.findViewById(R.id.pickerdate);

                            Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

                            pickerDate.init(
                                                today.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
                                                today.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
                                                today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 
                                                new OnDateChangedListener(){

                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) 
                                                 {

                                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDateChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                                                                            Editor et = pref.edit();

                                                                                            et.remove("year");

                                                                                            et.remove("month");

                                                                                            et.remove("day");

                                                                                            et.commit();

                                                                                            et.putInt("year", year);

                                                                                            et.putInt("month", monthOfYear);

                                                                                            et.putInt("day", dayOfMonth);

                                                                                            et.commit();

                                                 }});


                            btn12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                                            dia.dismiss();

                                            }
                            });

                            dia.show();

            }
   });

         MyShared ms = new MyShared();

            String save_date;
            try {

                            save_date = ms.execute().get();

                            info.setText("Result : "+save_date);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
            }


   }


   private class MyShared extends AsyncTask<String ,Void, String>
   {

                            String save_date = null;

                            SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Demo", 0);
                            @Override
                            protected  String  doInBackground(String... params) 
                            {


                                            int year = pref.getInt("year", 0);

                                              int month =  pref.getInt("month", 0);

                                              int day =   pref.getInt("day", 0);

                                                            String data = String.valueOf(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);

                                                            return data;

                            }
            }
 }
```

How can i get the latest saved result from my SharedPreference object. Please let me know , suggest me some good solution.

Comment: Update your code with proper indentation. It is not readable.

Comment: ok give me some time but please can you tell me a small thing that how to save Sharedpreference data in Android

Comment: You are doing it correctly as far as I can see. I will revisit the code, once you update it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code you init onDateChanged then execute the asynctask.

You get the first result.

Then the onDateChanged changes the preferences and you need to call it again.

code (not tested)

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    DatePicker pickerDate;
    TextView info;

    Button btn;


    Button btn12;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

        info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);

        final SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Demo", 0);

        new MyShared().execute();


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                final Dialog dia = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

                dia.requestWindowFeature(dia.getWindow().FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                dia.setContentView(R.layout.mydate);


                btn12 = (Button)dia.findViewById(R.id.btn1);

                pickerDate = (DatePicker)dia.findViewById(R.id.pickerdate);

                Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

                pickerDate.init(
                        today.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        today.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                        new OnDateChangedListener(){

                            @Override
                            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth)
                            {

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDateChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                Editor et = pref.edit();

                                et.remove("year");

                                et.remove("month");

                                et.remove("day");

                                et.commit();

                                et.putInt("year", year);

                                et.putInt("month", monthOfYear);

                                et.putInt("day", dayOfMonth);

                                et.commit();

                                new MyShared().execute();

                            }});


                btn12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        dia.dismiss();

                    }
                });

                dia.show();

            }
        });
    }


    private class MyShared extends AsyncTask<String ,Void, String>
    {
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Demo", 0);
        @Override
        protected  String  doInBackground(String... params)
        {


            int year = pref.getInt("year", 0);

            int month =  pref.getInt("month", 0);

            int day =   pref.getInt("day", 0);

            String data = String.valueOf(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);

            return data;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            info.setText(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After `dia.dismiss();` execute your asynctask.  i.e., write all code from `MyShared ms = new MyShared()...`  till `catch(ExecuteException e){}...`  after you dismiss the DatePicker.

This will dismiss the dialog and reads the data from sharedPreferences and updates the info.